# how to restrict drag elements to overlap in interact.js

Tags: overlapping

drag elements in container should not be overlap how can we restrict.
please help

[interact API link](http://interactjs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this was not answered sooner. I believe you have to manually check the position of the elements' top, bottom, left, and right edges, so here is what I did:

```
//Call this function from within your .on('dragmove') method.
//It should replace your translations.

function noOverlap(event, overlapElements){
    var dx = event.dx;
    var dy = event.dy;

    //just for flagging when the target would overlap another element
    var overlap = false;
    var targetDims = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    for(i = 0; i < overlapElements.length; i++){
        var overlapElementDims =  
        overlapElements[i].getBoundingClientRect();

        //make sure the element doesn't look at itself..
        if(overlapElements[i] != event.target){
            //checks if the target "doesn't" overlap
            if(((targetDims.right + dx) < (overlapElementDims.left + 1)) 
            ||((targetDims.left + 1 + dx) > (overlapElementDims.right)) 
            ||((targetDims.top + 1 + dy) > (overlapElementDims.bottom)) 
            ||((targetDims.bottom + dy) < (overlapElementDims.top + 1))){

            //Basically, the target element doesn't overlap the current 
            //element in the HTMLCollection, do nothing and go to the 
            //next iterate
            }
            else{
                //This is if the target element would overlap the current element

                //set overlap to true and break out of the for loop to conserve time.

                overlap = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    if(overlap === false){

        //if there's no overlap, do your normal stuff, like:
        event.target.x += dx;
        event.target.y += dy;

        event.target.style.webkitTransform =
            event.target.style.transform =
                'translate(' + event.target.x + 'px, ' + event.target.y + 'px)';

        //then reset dx and dy
        dy = 0;
        dx = 0;
    }
    else{
        if(event.interaction.pointers[event.interaction.pointers.length - 1].type 
        === "pointerup"){

            //check if the target "is" in the restriction zone
            var restriction = 
            interact(event.target).options.drag.restrict.restriction;
            var restrictionDims = restriction.getBoundingClientRect();

            if((targetDims.right > restrictionDims.right) || 
            (targetDims.left < restrictionDims.left) || 
            (targetDims.bottom > restrictionDims.bottom) || 
            (targetDims.top < restrictionDims.top)){
                event.target.style.webkitTransform =
                event.target.style.transform =
                    'translate(0px, 0px)';

                //then reset dx and dy
                dy = 0;
                dx = 0;

                //then reset x and y
                event.target.x = 0;
                event.target.y = 0;
            }
        }       
    } 
}
```

Comment: Also, if anyone ends up reading this, please let me know what all I could do to improve the efficiency.

Comment: I have stopped dragging by mot updating the positions of the dragged element, but any idea how I can stop the mouse pointer from moving in that case?

Comment: stopping the mouse pointer from moving is a completely different subject from interact js. I would look at something like this: http://www.smartjava.org/content/html5-use-pointer-lock-api-restrict-mouse-movement-element

Comment: Kirkland hi. Has this been folded into interact.js? It seems a v useful option and this is a bit too clever for me. I would much rather have a snap to non overlap. Seen "bricks" or something do that. Just wondering :-)