# how to restrict drag elements in interact.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, interact.js

I'm trying to stop my elements from overlapping using interact.js, but I don't have any idea how to get the n elements to be able to do it. Does anyone have an idea? Or some other way I can validate it.
Try the solution to this question, but I don't understand how to get the list of elements to go through it. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545130/how-to-restrict-drag-elements-to-overlap-in-interact-js)

```js
window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;

    interact('.signer-box')
        .draggable({
            onmove: dragMoveListener,
            inertia: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            restrict: {
                elementRect: {top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1}
            }
        })
        .resizable({
            onmove: resizeMoveListener,
            inertia: true,
            edges: {left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true}
        })

const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("signer-box");

function dragMoveListener(event) {
    
    const self = {
    x: event.target.offsetLeft + event.dx,
    y: event.target.offsetTop + event.dy,
    width: event.target.offsetWidth,
    height: event.target.offsetHeight
  }

  if (!collides(self, event)) {
    event.target.style.left = event.target.offsetLeft + event.dx + "px";
    event.target.style.top = event.target.offsetTop + event.dy + "px";
    var target = event.target;
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx;
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;
    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    
    computeSignerBoxPosition();
  }
   
}

function resizeMoveListener(event) {
    
     const self = {
    x: event.target.offsetLeft + event.deltaRect.left,
    y: event.target.offsetTop + event.deltaRect.top,
    width: event.target.offsetWidth + event.deltaRect.width,
    height: event.target.offsetHeight + event.deltaRect.height
  }

  if (!collides(self, event)) {
    var target = event.target;
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0);
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';
    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    
    computeSignerBoxPosition();
  }
 }   
    
    function collides(self, event) {
  for (const box of boxes) {
    if (box == event.target) {
      continue;
    }

    const other = {
      x: box.offsetLeft,
      y: box.offsetTop,
      width: box.offsetWidth,
      height: box.offsetHeight
    }

    const collisionX = Math.max(self.x + self.width, other.x + other.width) - Math.min(self.x, other.x) < self.width + other.width;
    const collisionY = Math.max(self.y + self.height, other.y + other.height) - Math.min(self.y, other.y) < self.height + other.height;

    if (collisionX && collisionY) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
   
}

function computeSignerBoxPosition() {
    var $signatureBox = $('.signer-box');
    var sbDataX = parseFloat($signatureBox.attr('data-x'));
    var sbDataY = parseFloat($signatureBox.attr('data-y'));
    var sbOuterWidth = $signatureBox.outerWidth();
    var sbOuterHeight = $signatureBox.outerHeight();

    var w = $('#pdf-page').width();
    var h = $('#pdf-page').height();
    
    var top = sbDataX / w;
    var left = sbDataY / h;
    var width = sbOuterWidth / w;
    var height = sbOuterHeight / h;

    document.getElementById("widthValue").value = width;
    document.getElementById("heightValue").value = height;
    document.getElementById("coorX").value = top;
    document.getElementById("coorY").value = left;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";


#pdf-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    user-select: none;
}

#pdf-page {
    width: 100%;
}

.signer-box {
   top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #29e no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0.2em 0.2em 0.5em;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

#values {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div id="pdf-container">
         <img id="pdf-page" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
            />
         
         
        <div id="signer-1" class="signer-box" data-x="379" data-y="279" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(379px, 279px); width: 148px; height: 90px; --content:&quot;Firma número 1&quot; ;"></div>
 <div id="signer-2" class="signer-box" data-x="17" data-y="30" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(17px, 30px); width: 238px; height: 121px; --content:&quot;Firma número 2&quot; ;"></div>
 
      </div>
      <div id="values">
         <label>X:
         <input id="coorX" readonly>
         </label>
         <label>Y:
         <input id="coorY" readonly>
         </label>
         <label>Width:
         <input id="widthValue" readonly>
         </label>
         <label>Height:
         <input id="heightValue" readonly>
         </label>
      </div>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.min.js'></script>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.9/interact.min.js'></script>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.worker.min.js'></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @jccampanero hello friend I have problems with the overlap I don't know if you have any ideas

Comment: Your html code is invalid, All the content elements are inside the ```<head>``` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need an answer that uses the CSS transform property I have made a new answer based on your changed code snippet with parts of my old answer. The collisions will be detected on the transform offsets and not the top and left properties. I hope you are helped with this answer.

```js
window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;

interact('.signer-box')
  .draggable({
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    inertia: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    restrict: {
      elementRect: {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 1,
        right: 1
      }
    }
  })
  .resizable({
    onmove: resizeMoveListener,
    inertia: true,
    edges: {
      left: true,
      right: true,
      bottom: true,
      top: true
    }
  })

const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("signer-box");

function dragMoveListener(event) {

  const self = {
    x: (parseFloat(event.target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
    y: (parseFloat(event.target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy,
    width: event.target.offsetWidth,
    height: event.target.offsetHeight
  };

  if (!collides(self, event)) {
    var target = event.target;
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx;
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;
    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);

    computeSignerBoxPosition(event.target);
  }

}

function resizeMoveListener(event) {

  const self = {
    x: (parseFloat(event.target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.deltaRect.left,
    y: (parseFloat(event.target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.deltaRect.top,
    width: event.rect.width,
    height: event.rect.height
  }

  if (!collides(self, event)) {
    var target = event.target;
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0);
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';
    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);

    computeSignerBoxPosition(event.target);
  }
}

function collides(self, event, tag = "") {
  for (const box of boxes) {
    if (box == event.target) {
      continue;
    }

    const other = {
      x: (parseFloat(box.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
      y: (parseFloat(box.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0),
      width: box.offsetWidth,
      height: box.offsetHeight
    }

    const collisionX = Math.max(self.x + self.width, other.x + other.width) - Math.min(self.x, other.x) < self.width + other.width;
    const collisionY = Math.max(self.y + self.height, other.y + other.height) - Math.min(self.y, other.y) < self.height + other.height;

    if (collisionX && collisionY) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function computeSignerBoxPosition(signer) {
  var $signatureBox = $(signer);
  var sbDataX = parseFloat($signatureBox.attr('data-x'));
  var sbDataY = parseFloat($signatureBox.attr('data-y'));
  var sbOuterWidth = $signatureBox.outerWidth();
  var sbOuterHeight = $signatureBox.outerHeight();

  var w = $('#pdf-page').width();
  var h = $('#pdf-page').height();

  var top = sbDataX / w;
  var left = sbDataY / h;
  var width = sbOuterWidth / w;
  var height = sbOuterHeight / h;

  document.getElementById("widthValue").value = width;
  document.getElementById("heightValue").value = height;
  document.getElementById("coorX").value = top;
  document.getElementById("coorY").value = left;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
#pdf-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

#pdf-page {
  width: 100%;
}

.signer-box {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #29e no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0.2em 0.2em 0.5em;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

#values {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="pdf-container">
    <img id="pdf-page" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    />


    <div id="signer-1" class="signer-box" data-x="379" data-y="279" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(379px, 279px); width: 148px; height: 90px; --content:&quot;Firma número 1&quot; ;"></div>
    <div id="signer-2" class="signer-box" data-x="17" data-y="30" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(17px, 30px); width: 238px; height: 121px; --content:&quot;Firma número 2&quot; ;"></div>

  </div>
  <div id="values">
    <label>X:
         <input id="coorX" readonly>
         </label>
    <label>Y:
         <input id="coorY" readonly>
         </label>
    <label>Width:
         <input id="widthValue" readonly>
         </label>
    <label>Height:
         <input id="heightValue" readonly>
         </label>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.9/interact.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.worker.min.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: perfect brother thank you very much, I will take into account what you mention, I have been having this problem for many weeks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is collision detection. When you move or resize your box you can check if the new dimensions/position does collide with other boxes. If that is the case then you can ignore the movement/resize.

Because your code snippet contained a lot of invalid HTML I had to strip most of it to make it work. Please do spend some time making valid HTML when/if you ask your next question. Some errors that were present in your HTML code:

- All content was made in the `<head>` element
- Usage of HTML tags. Only certain tags can exist out of one tag like `<br/>` is valid but `<div/>` is not and the proper way of writing some HTML tags like input is `<input>` (without closing tag)
- Closing tags `</tag>` without any starting tags `<tag>`
- Closing parent tags before closing all the child tags

```
<table>
  <div>
</table>
  </div>
```

Below is the solution i came up with:

```js
window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;
interact('.signer')
  .draggable({
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    inertia: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    restrict: {
      elementRect: {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 1,
        right: 1
      }
    }
  })
  .resizable({
    onmove: resizeMoveListener,
    inertia: true,
    edges: {
      left: true,
      right: true,
      bottom: true,
      top: true
    }
  })

const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("signer");

function dragMoveListener(event) {
  const self = {
    x: event.target.offsetLeft + event.dx,
    y: event.target.offsetTop + event.dy,
    width: event.target.offsetWidth,
    height: event.target.offsetHeight
  }

  if (!collides(self, event)) {
    event.target.style.left = event.target.offsetLeft + event.dx + "px";
    event.target.style.top = event.target.offsetTop + event.dy + "px";
    setInfo(self);
  }
}

function resizeMoveListener(event) {
  const self = {
    x: event.target.offsetLeft + event.deltaRect.left,
    y: event.target.offsetTop + event.deltaRect.top,
    width: event.target.offsetWidth + event.deltaRect.width,
    height: event.target.offsetHeight + event.deltaRect.height
  }

  if (!collides(self, event)) {
    event.target.style.left = self.x + "px";
    event.target.style.top = self.y + "px";
    event.target.style.width = self.width + "px";
    event.target.style.height = self.height + "px";
    setInfo(self);
  }
}

function setInfo(dimensions) {
  document.getElementById("x").value = dimensions.x;
  document.getElementById("y").value = dimensions.y;
  document.getElementById("width").value = dimensions.width;
  document.getElementById("height").value = dimensions.height;
}

function collides(self, event) {
  for (const box of boxes) {
    if (box == event.target) {
      continue;
    }

    const other = {
      x: box.offsetLeft,
      y: box.offsetTop,
      width: box.offsetWidth,
      height: box.offsetHeight
    }

    const collisionX = Math.max(self.x + self.width, other.x + other.width) - Math.min(self.x, other.x) < self.width + other.width;
    const collisionY = Math.max(self.y + self.height, other.y + other.height) - Math.min(self.y, other.y) < self.height + other.height;

    if (collisionX && collisionY) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.signer {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #29e no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0.2em 0.2em 0.5em;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

.signer:nth-child(2) {
  left: 300px;
}

#values {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="pdf-container">
    <img id="pdf-page" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    />
    <div class="signer"></div>
    <div class="signer"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="values">
    <label>X:
        <input id="x" readonly>
      </label>
    <label>Y:
        <input id="y" readonly>
      </label>
    <label>Width:
        <input id="width" readonly>
      </label>
    <label>Height:
        <input id="height" readonly>
      </label>
  </div>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.9/interact.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.worker.min.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that collision detection is done with the so-called AABB collision detection algorithm. It might not be the most efficient collision detection algorithm but it's one of the simplest to implement. And since you have only 2 boxes this algorithm is sufficient. If you need more boxes this algorithm will become exponentially slower and you might want to invest time researching for a better algorithm, for example, a quadtree.

Comment: hello friend thank you very much for your answer, I have tried to replicate your answer but I have not succeeded, I have edited the question, could you help me? since you added giving your solution now I can't move any boxes

Comment: I can see why it doesn't work the collision detection works with the properties offsetTop, offsetLeft, and the way you position your elements is with a transform. Do you really need the transform for this? What is the reason you need a transform?

Comment: @SebastianRuiz check my new answer